# Avoiding display mode in numbered equation

Tags: equations, numbering

Is there a way to write a numbered equation avoiding the display mode. Meaning it is possible to number things written between single $ symbols?

Comment: `\begin{equation}\textstyle ... \end{equation}` might do for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\refstepcounter{equation} (\theequation) $1=1$

\refstepcounter{equation} (\theequation) $2=2$
```